# Changed jobs. Email from last job is now dead and that is log in for my google scholar

Tags: google-scholar

I have changed jobs.  My email from my last job is now dead and that is log in for my google scholar account.  How do I get round this?

Comment: Sadly it is dead. The IT felt from last job scrubbed my accounts as is their policy after a few months

Comment: If it is just the "username" then it probably doesn't matter and you can continue to use it without effect. Many sites, at least, work like that. Have you tried to login and it failed?

Answer (score 2):

The email is most likely not dead, you simply don't have access anymore. Ask your former employer to help you change the mail (by forwarding you the confirmation mail, for example).